# Denying access to my adserver to third-parties

Tags: .htaccess, access-denied, advertisement-server

I have this situation:
An user with IP X visit my website with IP Y. The website has an external < script > tag which get information from an AdServer Z (< script src=Z/script.js />) and display an Ad.

Now, I want to block X accessing Z/script.js directly, but when the user visit the website, it display the Ad.

I tried with an .htaccess doing this:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from Y
Deny from all
```

But it doens't display Ads and I can't access the file directly.

But when I did this:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from X
Deny from all
```

The website display Ads and I can access the file directly.

I thought that the Apache on Z would received Y as IP but apparently is receiving X.
Why is this?
And what can I do to protect Z from users but my website can link the files.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly linking to the adserver, and not proxying. That means when someone loads the page from your webserver, and the browser renders `<script src=ADSERVER/script.js>`, the browser sends a request directly to the ADSERVER. There is nothing you can do about the browser *not* loading this resource unless you change the URL.

You can change the URL to point to a URL on your server, and proxy it. For example, say you change the URL from `http://ADSERVER/script.js` to `/adserver/script.js`.

You can do this with ProxyPass (in vhost or server config only):

```
    ProxyPass /adserver/script.js http://ADSERVER/script.js
```

Or mod_rewrite (in htaccess, server or vhost config, but mod_proxy must be loaded):

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?adserver/script.js http://ADSERVER/script.js [L,P]
```

Then on the ad server, only allow access from Y (your webserver).

Comment: It was a good solution. It worked.
The problem is that that script does a document.write loading more scripts of the ADSERVER and does scripts again return in a Error 403.

Comment: @xotihcan if the output of your adserver scripts contain URLs for more adserver scripts then maybe you want to consider using something like [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/)